# Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." error with app, only on thirdparty AD

Tags: validation, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I am trying to search for users in my own and a third party Azure Active Directoriy via the application access flow.
I use the following to get a valid token.

```
string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", "<AD>.onmicrosoft.com");
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(<clientId>, <appKey>);

AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net" , clientCredential);
string TokenForApplication = result.AccessToken;
```

I use this method to search for users with a given name.

```
public async Task<List<IUser>> UsersSearch(IActiveDirectoryClient client, string searchString)
{
    List<IUser> usersList = null;
    IPagedCollection<IUser> searchResults = null;

    IUserCollection userCollection = client.Users;
    searchResults = await userCollection.Where(user =>
        user.UserPrincipalName.StartsWith(searchString) ||
        user.GivenName.StartsWith(searchString)).Take(10).ExecuteAsync();
    usersList = searchResults.CurrentPage.ToList();

    return usersList;
}
```

This all works fine on the Azure AD where I first setup the app.

But when when I try to use the app in another Azure Active directory I get the error: `Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."`

In my original Azure AD I have set all the permissions I need for the app to access the graph API and search for users:

[image: permissions on my own AAD]

In the third party Azure AD I have gone through the Admin flow and granted the app all the needed permissions:

[image: Permissions for app on Third party AAD]

As far as I can see I get a valid token to each Azure AD, but I keep getting the same error whenever I try to access the third party Azure AD.

The way I change what AD I am trying to access is by changing `<AD>` in

```
string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", "<AD>.onmicrosoft.com");
```

I keep everything else the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot , the selected permissions is for Microsoft Graph API(https://graph.microsoft.com) , but according to your code , you are acquiring token for Azure AD Graph api(https://graph.windows.net) .

If you want to use Azure AD Graph api , you should add permissions for `Windows Azure Active Directory` in `Required permissions` blade of your multi-tenant app , and do admin consent in other AAD .

if you want to use Microsoft Graph API , you should modify your code , use `https://graph.microsoft.com` instead of `https://graph.windows.net` .

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise I was actually using the Azure AD Graph API!
If I change the endpoint I get "BadRequest": "Invalid version", which I gather would mean I need to change my code to use a different set of calls?

Comment: You want to use Azure AD Graph API or microsoft graph api ? Your sdk seems using azure ad graph api  .

Comment: Yes, I understood from your answer that I am currently using Azure AD graph API. I would like to use Microsoft graph API.

Comment: OK, then you need to make [microsoft graph api list users operation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list) . And microsoft graph provides .net sdk , you could check the code samples from [here](https://github.com/search?q=aspnet+sample+user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories) , especially [this one](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample) .